# calculating windowed probabilities in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to do a bit of (I think) an obscure filter on an image using numpy/scipy. What I want is essentially a windowed probability distribution. I start with a grayscale image. For a given pixel and an `NxN` kernel, with `N` odd, I want to calculate that pixel value's probability, relative to the other pixels in the kernel. Furthermore, I want to do this calculation as fast as possible.

So for example given a 3x3 region of an image:

```
[0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0;
 255, 255, 255]
```

The center pixel should be converted from `0` to `0.66` since it has a 2/3 chance of occurring in that 3x3 region. In code, I can do as follows, but it's way too slow:

```
# loops through calculating probability distributions for each window
# generates new_image
for yi in range(0, height):
  for xi in range(0, width):
    window = kernel_region(image, yi, xi, ksize)
    hist = np.histogram(window.ravel(), 256, [0, 256])
    pdf = hist / np.size(window)
    pixel_value = image[yi, xi]
    new_image[yi, xi] = pdf[pixel_value]

# gives ksize x ksize slice of the image (smaller on the edges)
def kernel_region(image, yi, xi, ksize):
  height, width = image.shape[:2]
  offset = math.floor(ksize / 2)
  yStart = max(0, yi - offset)
  yEnd = min(height - 1, yi + offset)
  xStart = max(0, xi - offset)
  xEnd = min(width - 1, xi + offset)
  return image[yStart:yEnd, xStart:xEnd]
```

There are some optimizations I could make in the loop but I'd like to avoid using a loop at all. Is this possible using "pure" numpy functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting math problem and seems like there would be a simple solution with [`Scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get `(3,3)` sliding windows and then comparing against the center pixel for getting the count of its occurrence in its window and finally dividing by the kernel size of `9`.

Hence, the implementation for an image `a` would be -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

(view_as_windows(a,(3,3)) == a[1:-1,1:-1,None,None]).sum((-2,-1))/9.0
```

This gets us the results for the non-boundary elements. To cover for all the elements, we can pad the image with an invalid specifier, say `-1` around it and then use the proposed method.

Sample run -

```
In [61]: a
Out[61]: 
array([[  1,   0,   0,   0,   3,   4],
       [  2,   0,   0,   0,   6,   0],
       [  4, 255, 255, 255,   8,   2],
       [  0,   5,   0,   5,   6,   2]])

In [76]: (view_as_windows(a,(3,3)) == a[1:-1,1:-1,None,None]).sum((-2,-1))/9.0
Out[76]: 
array([[ 0.44,  0.67,  0.44,  0.11],
       [ 0.22,  0.33,  0.22,  0.11]])
```

To cover for all elements -

```
In [74]: a1 = np.pad(a, (1,1), 'constant', constant_values=(-1, -1))

In [75]: (view_as_windows(a1,(3,3)) == a1[1:-1,1:-1,None,None]).sum((-2,-1))/9.0
Out[75]: 
array([[ 0.11,  0.44,  0.67,  0.44,  0.11,  0.11],
       [ 0.11,  0.44,  0.67,  0.44,  0.11,  0.11],
       [ 0.11,  0.22,  0.33,  0.22,  0.11,  0.22],
       [ 0.11,  0.11,  0.11,  0.11,  0.11,  0.22]])
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer. As follow up, what if I wanted to take it a step further and compute a probability distribution for each window? For example, in your first example (input 6x4, no padding), the output would be of shape `(4, 2, 3, 3)` or equivalently, `(12, 6)`, where each `3x3` window is a full probability distribution. In my original example: `[[0.67, 0.67, 0.67], [0.67, 0.67, 0.67], [0.33, 0.33, 0.33]]`